# Magento 2 minicart Items Issue

Tags: mini-cart, magento2.1.5

How to remove replace null value in place of Zero(0) in minicart if **There is no items in cart** in magento2?

Comment: Have you applied my answer solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code to :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

```
<!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <span class="counter-number">0</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Just after this code

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```